# Removing Chapter from the Chapter heading using a.cls file

Tags: chapters

Sorry if this is an easy question, however I am relatively new to LaTeX and have been trying to understand some of the code in a .cls file.

I'm trying to remove the Chapter from the \chapter headings and in the .cls file there is this code:

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {
    \begin{center}
      \normalfont\heading
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter\heading\@chapapp\ \thechapter:\ \fi %\thechapter:\ \fi
      \fi
      \heading #1\par\nobreak
      \vskip 20\p@
    \end{center}
  }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what I'm meant to be changing to remove the 'Chapter' part of Chapter 1: Introduction.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest writing in the preamble: `\renewcommand\chaptername{\relax}`. Or you can use the  `titlesec` package thats allows complete re-formatting chaters, sections and so on.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for the tip! That was a quick fix without having to mess with the .cls file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class is non standard, but the code can be easily interpreted: `\heading` is probably a font selection command defined in the class, whereas `\@chapapp` is the kernel macro that expands either to `\chaptername` or to `\appendixname`, choosing the latter after an `\appendix` declaration has been processed.

So omitting the fixed word “Chapter” (more precisely, what's contained in the macro `\chaptername`) is obtained by removing `\@chapapp` and the space `\` after it.

Also the first `\heading` command is sufficient for setting the font, so it can be omitted in the other places. However, you shouldn't modify the class, but rather put this code in the preamble of your document:

```
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {
    \begin{center}
      \normalfont\heading
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter\thechapter:\ \fi %\thechapter:\ \fi
      \fi
      #1\par\nobreak
      \vskip 20\p@
    \end{center}
  }
}

\makeatother
```

If you decide to modify the class, omit `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (but don't do it this way).

Comment: Thank you for your help! It's made me understand the code a lot better :)